# Am I allowed to squash commits in repository with Apache 2.0 license?

Tags: apache-2.0, forking, git

The repository of an open-source Apache 2.0 licensed project I'm forking is huge and has a giant commit history, so, for the sake of saving space, I want to just to squash all commits, preserving all the file structure and, of course, the license and contributors list.

Is it an OK action? From what I read and deduced it's totally fine - the license is about the product itself, not about the commit history. Still, I want to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell, the Apache license allows you to modify the source code as long as you document your changes. You could view squashing the commits as such a change, and document it by stating something like "This project is forked from XYZ, with commit history .. squashed".